# Data from view to list

Tags: c#

I have a view which returns me data of following rows- Id,SourceStatus,StatusId, ActivePre, Runtime.
In c# i have created a class and have written a parameterized query to get data.

```
public class TestClass
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool? SourceStatus { get; set; }

    public int? StatusId{ get; set; }

    public int? ActivePre { get; set; }

    public string Runtime { get; set; }
}


string mydata= "SELECT * FROM view1 WHERE Id = {0}";
deviceData.TestList = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<TestClass>(mydata, deviceId).ToList();
```

In deviceData.TestList i am getting the data perfectly. My challenge is , I need to get this data in another list- HeaderData

```
public class HeaderData
{
    public STRING Name { get; set; }
    public STRING Value { get; set; }

}
```

such that my list looks - { Name: Assetid, value:1 , Name :SourceStatus , value :false }. I am currently doing it like below. Bit i do understand it is a horrible way.How Can i do it better?

```
      deviceData.HeaderData= new List<HeaderData>();
      foreach( var v in deviceData.TestList)
            {
                deviceData.HeaderData.Add(new HeaderData() { Name = "Id" , Value = v.ActivePreset});
                deviceData.HeaderData.Add(new DeviceHeaderData() { Name = "SourceStatus", Value = v.SourceStatus });
                deviceData.HeaderEntries.Add(new DeviceHeaderData() { Name = "Runtime", Value = v.Runtime });
            }
```

Comment: The question is do you really need another class to show the same data? Maybe you just want to use a different view. Wpf is quite good at data templating some controls. I think at the moment, your scenario is a bit unclear what you want to use the data for (this could actually be usefull in solving your problem)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
// Get property array
var properties = GetProperties(some_object);

foreach (var p in properties)
{
    string name = p.Name;
    var value = p.GetValue(some_object, null);
}

private static PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this may be?

```
    deviceData.HeaderData = deviceData.TestList.select
                            ( x => new HeaderData { Name = x.name, Value = x.value} )
                           .toList();
```

haven't test this code, this is just an example, for this code to work, you have to add name property && value property to.

> TestList class